# Setting connectionInitSqls on iBatis DBCP dataSource

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

I'm trying to set connectionInitSqls property on iBatis sql-map-config.xml for my DB connection. Documentation says it should be a list of sql statements, but I don't know how to configure it on the xml file.

I have tried the following approach:

```
<property name="connectionInitSqls">
   <list>
      <value>SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'</value>
   </list>
</property>
```

But, it gives me an error message saying that "Attribute 'value' is required and it must be specified for element type 'property'".

Here is how the sql-map-config.xml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
<sqlMapConfig>
    <properties resource="config/properties/dev/jdbc.properties" />
    <transactionManager type="JDBC">
        <dataSource type="DBCP">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
            <property name="connectionInitSqls">
                <list>
                    <value>SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </dataSource>
    </transactionManager>
</sqlMapConfig>
```

How to specify the list of 'connectionInitSqls' correctly on the sql-map-config.xml file?